# 3 table Linq Query

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-ce

I Have 3 Relational Tables on SQLCE Database.

Product       ProductCategory     ProductPhoto

----------      ----------------------     -----------------

PId              CatId                          PhotoId

Name          Name                          Value

CatId                                              PId

I Need, List ProductCategories with first Product Photo for Linq.

If not possible Linq, please sql code.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you got so far? StackOverflow is a place to offer advice, not code. :)

Comment: Merhaba Serkan :) Konu nedir?

Comment: @BeratBilgin 3 tablodan, kategorileri listelerken, ürüne bağlı ilk fotoğrafı da çekmek istiyorum.

Comment: @SerkanCeylan David B'nin Cevabı yeterli sanırım.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pc in ProductCategories
let photo = pc.Products.SelectMany(p => p.Photos).FirstOrDefault()
select new {pc, photo};
```